# XMLHttp request in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I am using below code to send the HTTP request using IE 11.

```
 httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {};
 httpRequest.open('GET', myURL);
 httpRequest.send();
```

This sends request to the localhost from my website.

It works fine and faster in Firefox and Chrome. But in IE 11 it is not consistent, that it sometimes works and sometimes not.

I also tried the Code,

```
var req = document.createElement("img");
req.src = myURL;
```

But didn't help. Is there anything which I need to add or change?

Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: show the full code, where you create httpRequest.

Comment: Hi VLAS, inside the function I just use var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {};
 httpRequest.open('GET', myURL);
 httpRequest.send();